# Writing a Singleton in Swift for Squeal

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Im using [Squeal](https://github.com/nerdyc/Squeal) to access a Sqlite database for my app. I want to write it as a Singleton helper class, but I can't figure out how to create a class global version of `db`.

Heres the code for the whole file:

```
import Foundation

import Squeal

class DatabaseHelper {
    static let sharedInstance = DatabaseHelper()

    let databaseFile = "record_store.db"

    private init() {
        let db = Database(path:databaseFile)

        // Create the table
        db?.createTable(
            "Records",
            definitions: [
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
                "Artist TEXT",
                "Album TEXT",
                "Gnere TEXT",
                "Year TEXT",
                "Size TEXT",
                "Speed Text"
            ]
        )

        NSLog("Database Created")
    }

    func Insert() {
        NSLog("Inserting stuff")
    }

    func Delete() {
        NSLog("Deleting stuff")
    }
}
```

So how can I make that `db` accessible to the whole class? I tried declaring

```
let db
```

and

```
let db = Database(path:databaseFile)
```

but both throw errors that I don't know how to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ali Beadle had the correct answer. I wanted to expand upon that with the full example for you to make this more clear.

I've also made the `databaseFile` constant private. I don't think you need other people accessing the file name, just the actual database.

```
import Foundation

import Squeal

class DatabaseHelper {
static let sharedInstance = DatabaseHelper()

private let databaseFile = "record_store.db"

let db: Database

private init() {
    db = Database(path:databaseFile)

    // Create the table
    db?.createTable(
        "Records",
        definitions: [
            "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
            "Artist TEXT",
            "Album TEXT",
            "Gnere TEXT",
            "Year TEXT",
            "Size TEXT",
            "Speed Text"
        ]
    )

    NSLog("Database Created")
}

func Insert() {
    NSLog("Inserting stuff")
}

func Delete() {
    NSLog("Deleting stuff")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your init use:

```
let db:Database
```

But then within the init change:

```
let db = Database(path:databaseFile)
```

To:

```
db = Database(path:databaseFile)
```